# Create more than one parameter swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I'm facing some issues trying to create more than one parameter for a route.

I have the id from request parameters (path) which is ap araemter from the path and another parameter, the content from the body (request body) .

I can't find a way to put together working like the example below:

```
parameters:
        - name: data
          in: body
          description: data object
        - name: alertId
          in: "path"
          description: alert id
          required: true
          type: string
```

But I'm facing the problem where the parameter input should be "header, formData, query, path" liek the image below.

How can i do this? I tried to change the "swager: 2.0" info in the top of the document to "openapi: 3.0.0" but don't work either.

[image]

Comment: The body parameter needs a `schema`. See the answer in [Swagger Format for PayPal Payment API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42339837/swagger-format-for-paypal-payment-api)

Comment: i remove all schemas when i use input type "path". It  worked for the body. thanks